# Archive failed with XCode 10, Cocoapods and New Build System

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am not sure, if this is Cocoapods related - maybe yes.

I have pretty complex project with few development Pods included. When using xCode 10 with new build system enabled, the build behaves unreliable. The first clean build is fine, however when I change something in development pod, the xCode looks like it correctly compile changes - but when I run the changed app in the simulator, the changes are simply not there. When I try to debug this code, xCode displays correct changed source code, but the code executed is old.

When I change back to "legacy" build system, everything works fine.

Anybody with similar experience?

Thanks,

Oktay

Comment: Maybe you need to add the dependency on the pod target explicitly with the new build system? You could try to manually rebuild the pod target, then run the app again -- if you see the correct behavior it means that the pod target is not automatically rebuilt when running the main target.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Not resolved yet. I think, the pod is recompiled fine. I checked files in DerivedData/Build folder at it looks like the target files are recompiled (files has actual creation time). Bud in the final app package, there is the old version of that framework from Cocoapods. When I do clean build everythink is fine.

Comment: It seems copy pod resources script not executed. Or asset.car conflict

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8151) to revert to the "Legacy Build System" in File > Workspace Settings

Answer (score 0):

It has been discussed here. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8073
It is a bug in xcode and the option is to manipulate with script files, so the embed script is run everytime.